# how we can handle exceptions in procedures in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

In many RDBMS Databases there is a mechanism to handle the exception in stored procedures and functions. Is there any way in bigquery to handle the run time exceptions? Like `no data found` or `subscript beyond count`?

Answer (score 6):

BigQuery hasn't documented it yet, but you can handle any type of exception in BigQuery by creating an exception handling clause, as described in the following example:

```sql
BEGIN
  SELECT 1/0;
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
  SELECT @@error.message, @@error.statement_text;
END;
```

In the above example, the EXCEPTION block is entered whenever an exception occurs in the BEGIN block above it.  Inside the exception block, @@error.message evaluates to a string describing the error, and @@error.statement_text is the text of the statement which caused the error.

Be aware that, as this feature has not been formally documented yet, the syntax is still subject to change.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone who might be looking at this reference, the documentation for this is available here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#beginexceptionend

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any exception handling in BigQuery. Anyway, if your concern is to handle the runtime exception you should be able to do this through the SAFE method.

For example, the following piece of code would return Null in case an error is created by the SUBSTR function.

```
SELECT SAFE.SUBSTR('bar', 0, 2) AS safe_output;
```

Further info you can find the at the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe-prefix) This should cover up your use case if I understood correctly your need.